# Not able to install Integration app on real device

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

Error Detail :

Details

Unable to install "IntegrationApp"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620415

```
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620415
Failure Reason: An unknown error has occurred.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001201796e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000120179de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001201b956a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106181c12 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001201b9301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000120041a25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001062b2e7a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001062b4552 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5be875f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5be8863d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5be8e8e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5be8f396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff5be976ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5c0c8611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5c0c83fd start_wqthread + 13
);
}
```

--

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your apple id is associated with the developer account.
I had same problem and sorted out by changing the my apple id